# Drop/ Delete Database in Teradata

Tags: teradata

Please help with direction on how to drop a database in Teradata.
When I run the command `DROP DATABASE database_name`, I get the error message:

```
*** Failure 3552 Cannot DROP databases with tables, journal tables, 
views, macros, or zones.
            Statement# 1, Info =0
*** Total elapsed time was 1 second.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run this command first to delete all of the objects in the database:

```
DELETE DATABASE database_name;
```

In order to drop a database with journal tables:

```
MODIFY DATABASE database_name AS DROP DEFAULT JOURNAL TABLE;
```

Then run,

```
DROP DATABASE database_name
```

to delete the database in Teradata

Comment: I now get the error `Teradata error 3552 Cannot DROP databases with tables, journal tables, views, or macros.`

Comment: Was the `DELETE` statement above successfully executed?

Comment: Yes, but it was `DELETE DATABASE database_name ALL` that worked

Comment: Okay, figured it out, I also needed to run,  
`MODIFY database database_name as DROP default journal table;` before running `DROP DATABASE database_name`;

Comment: You didn't mention you had journal tables.  Glad you found a solution.